# php exec() function not working for all commands on ubuntu + nginx + fpm

Tags: shell, php

I can see the result of:

```
echo exec("whoami"); // will output "www-data"
```

however if I try to run a real world command:

```
echo exec("casperjs myscript.js /foo/bar");
```

then nothing happens:

- no output (the casperjs script should output some stdout log messages)
- no action (the script should create an image, using an absolute path, but it doesn't)
- no errors from PHP
- no output of the shell command

I've searched on StackOverflow, and went to try alternative ways (tested first in the shell, to be sure they work):

```
echo exec("casperjs /absolute/path/to/myscript.js");
echo exec("/usr/local/bin/casperjs /absolute/path/to/myscript.js");
```

I tested also other combinations, using `system()`, `shell_exec()` and even `passthru()`
but it's always the same thing: no error, no output, even in php log files, so it is very, very hard to understand the problem :(

Comment: When you test in the shell, are you the same user (`www-data`)? The web server might be `chroot`'d to a specific directory for security reasons.

Comment: Is `safe_mode` enabled? This limits the directories that `exec()` can run commands from.

Comment: @nickb nice point, in the shell I run as 'ubuntu', I'm gonna check this out!

Comment: @Barmar I've checked `safe_mode` using `phpinfo()` and it is disabled (set to Off)

Comment: Ok so I've tested in my shell using `sudo -su www-data` and it worked. By the way the script to be executed by Casper is located, and operated in a directory whose tree is owned (group) by `www-data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `echo exec("casperjs myscript.js /foo/bar 2>&1");` to redirect stderr to stdout which wouldn't otherwise show.

It could be an error in your cmdline or maybe casperjs is not in your $PATH, etc.

Comment: Ok, I've found the answer using your tip! CasperJS being based on PhantomJS, it needs a X server so I can't run the command on a web server (however, I think there is a minimal/headless mode, and headless X server, so I'll check this out)